# Простой калькулятор на JS. Не так работает при кастомизации чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простенький калькулятор с чекбоксами. В какой-то момент потребовалось изменить  функционал чекбоксов (с этим помогли, спасибо), что бы они работали как радио кнопки, но можно было снять чек. 
И вот с этим кодом калькулятор складывает всегда значения, даже когда мы снимаем чек. Помогите понять, как решить эту проблему?

```js
function calculator() {
  let dopServ = $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv");

  let totals = dopServ;
  $(".totalprice__price").text(totals);
  $(".totalprice__total").val(totals)
}

// Проблема где-то тут

$(".banner1__check input").on('change', function() {

  let currentPrice = $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv");
  let servPrice = $(this).attr("price");
  if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
    let total = +currentPrice - +servPrice;
    $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv", total)
  } else {
    let total = +currentPrice + +servPrice;
    $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv", total)
  }
  calculator()
});

// Что бы чекбокс был как radio

const cover = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cover"]');

const uncheck = (evt) => {
  cover.forEach((ch) => {
    if (ch !== evt.currentTarget) {
      ch.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

cover.forEach((ch) => ch.addEventListener('change', uncheck));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="thanks.php" method="post" class="banner1__form flex banner1__form--active">
  <div class="banner1__col banner1__col_2 flex">
    <div class="calc__dop-custom banner1__input-g">
      <label class="banner1__input-g-label">Покрытие пола:</label>
      <div class="calc__dop-custom-inputs">
        <div class="banner1__input banner1__input-g">
          <div class="banner1__check check-new">
            <input id="linoleum" price="800" name="cover" type="checkbox" class="radio-check">
            <label for="linoleum" price="800">линолеум</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner1__input">
          <div class="banner1__check">
            <input id="parquet" price="1500" name="cover" type="checkbox" class="radio-check">
            <label price="1500" for="parquet">паркетная доска</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner1__check check-old">
      <p>Другое</p>
      <input id="check5" type="checkbox" price="1700">
      <label for="check5" price="1700">Материал нашей компании</label>
    </div>
    <div class="totalprice flex">
      <span class="totalprice__price" dop-serv="0" square="1" rem-type="" rem-price="0">0</span>
      <span class="totalprice__curr">руб.</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="total20" class="totalprice__total">
    <input type="text" name="type20" class="totalprice__type">
    <input type="text" name="dop20" class="totalprice__dop">
    <button class="btn banner__order4" name="sendForm20" type="submit">Зафиксировать
         цену</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут проще при подсчете суммы просто проходить по чекбоксам и, если он активный, прибавлять его стоимость, а сейчас у вас берется всегда стоимость из тотала и к ней прибавляется цена.

```js
function calculator() {
  let dopServ = $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv");

  let totals = dopServ;
  $(".totalprice__price").text(totals);
  $(".totalprice__total").val(totals)
}

// Что бы чекбокс был как radio

const cover = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cover"]');

const uncheck = (evt) => {
  cover.forEach((ch) => {
    if (ch !== evt.currentTarget) {
      ch.checked = false;
    }
  });
}

cover.forEach((ch) => ch.addEventListener('change', uncheck));

// Проблема где-то тут

$(".banner1__check input").on('change', function() {
  let total = 0;
  $(".banner1__check input").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      total += Number($(this).attr('price'));
    }
  })
  $(".totalprice__price").attr("dop-serv", total)
  calculator()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="thanks.php" method="post" class="banner1__form flex banner1__form--active">
  <div class="banner1__col banner1__col_2 flex">
    <div class="calc__dop-custom banner1__input-g">
      <label class="banner1__input-g-label">Покрытие пола:</label>
      <div class="calc__dop-custom-inputs">
        <div class="banner1__input banner1__input-g">
          <div class="banner1__check check-new">
            <input id="linoleum" price="800" name="cover" type="checkbox" class="radio-check">
            <label for="linoleum" price="800">линолеум</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner1__input">
          <div class="banner1__check">
            <input id="parquet" price="1500" name="cover" type="checkbox" class="radio-check">
            <label price="1500" for="parquet">паркетная доска</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner1__check check-old">
      <p>Другое</p>
      <input id="check5" type="checkbox" price="1700">
      <label for="check5" price="1700">Материал нашей компании</label>
    </div>
    <div class="totalprice flex">
      <span class="totalprice__price" dop-serv="0" square="1" rem-type="" rem-price="0">0</span>
      <span class="totalprice__curr">руб.</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="total20" class="totalprice__total">
    <input type="text" name="type20" class="totalprice__type">
    <input type="text" name="dop20" class="totalprice__dop">
    <button class="btn banner__order4" name="sendForm20" type="submit">Зафиксировать
         цену</button>
  </div>
</form>
```